# Individual Authentication in a Blazor project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have created my new Blazor project that consists of the server, client and shared projects.  In order to authenticate the users, in the server project I added some custom fields in the `ApplicationDbContext` such as `FirstName` and `ProfilePicture`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}
```

So, in the server application, I changed the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` like that (I added spaces in the `src` to have a more clear line)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using LIU.Website.Server.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item" style="align-self: center;">
            @if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ProfilePicture != null)
            {
                <img style="width:40px;height:40px; object-fit:cover; border-radius:30px" 
                     src="data:image/*;base64,
                     @(Convert.ToBase64String(
                       UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)
                                  .Result.ProfilePicture))">
            }
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" 
               asp-area="Identity" 
               asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">
               Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
        </li>

        <!-- ... -->
    }
    else
    {
        <!-- ... -->
    }
</ul>
```

Now, I like to have the same picture in the client. I added the same code but in this case, I have only the standard fields, not my custom fields

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="authentication/profile">Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</a>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

How can I have access to my custom fields? Do I have to add in the client project the dependencies to `SignInManager` and `UserManager`?